# How to filter jCal with jq?

Tags: arrays, json, filter, jq

I have an jCal JSON array which I'd like to filter with jq. JSON arrays are somewhat new to me and I have been banging my head to the wall on this for hours...

The file looks like this:

```json
[
  "vcalendar",
  [
    [
      "calscale",
      {},
      "text",
      "GREGORIAN"
    ],
    [
      "version",
      {},
      "text",
      "2.0"
    ],
    [
      "prodid",
      {},
      "text",
      "-//SabreDAV//SabreDAV//EN"
    ],
    [
      "x-wr-calname",
      {},
      "unknown",
      "Call log private"
    ],
    [
      "x-apple-calendar-color",
      {},
      "unknown",
      "#ffaa00"
    ],
    [
      "refresh-interval",
      {},
      "duration",
      "PT4H"
    ],
    [
      "x-published-ttl",
      {},
      "unknown",
      "PT4H"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "vevent",
      [
        [
          "dtstamp",
          {},
          "date-time",
          "2015-04-05T16:42:10Z"
        ],
        [
          "created",
          {},
          "date-time",
          "2015-02-18T16:44:04Z"
        ],
        [
          "uid",
          {},
          "text",
          "9b23142b-8d86-3e17-2f44-2bed65b2e471"
        ],
        [
          "last-modified",
          {},
          "date-time",
          "2015-04-05T16:42:10Z"
        ],
        [
          "description",
          {},
          "text",
          "Phone call to +49xxxxxxxxxx lasted for 0 seconds."
        ],
        [
          "summary",
          {},
          "text",
          "Outgoing: +49xxxxxxx"
        ],
        [
          "dtstart",
          {},
          "date-time",
          "2015-02-18T10:58:12Z"
        ],
        [
          "dtend",
          {},
          "date-time",
          "2015-02-18T10:58:44Z"
        ],
        [
          "transp",
          {},
          "text",
          "OPAQUE"
        ]
      ],
      []
    ],
    [
      "vevent",
      [
        [
          "dtstamp",
          {},
          "date-time",
          "2015-04-05T16:42:10Z"
        ],
        [
          "created",
          {},
          "date-time",
          "2015-01-09T19:12:05Z"
        ],
        [
          "uid",
          {},
          "text",
          "c337e092-a012-5f5a-497f-932fbc6159e5"
        ],
        [
          "last-modified",
          {},
          "date-time",
          "2015-04-05T16:42:10Z"
        ],
        [
          "description",
          {},
          "text",
          "Phone call to +1xxxxxxxxxx lasted for 39 seconds."
        ],
        [
          "summary",
          {},
          "text",
          "Outgoing: +1xxxxxxxxxx"
        ],
        [
          "dtstart",
          {},
          "date-time",
          "2015-01-09T17:23:16Z"
        ],
        [
          "dtend",
          {},
          "date-time",
          "2015-01-09T17:24:19Z"
        ],
        [
          "transp",
          {},
          "text",
          "OPAQUE"
        ]
      ],
      []
    ],
  ]
]
```

I would like to filter out dtstart, dtend, the target phone number and the connection duration from the description for each vevent which was created e.g. in January 2019 ("2019-01.*") and output them as a CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JSON is a bit strange because the information is stored position-based in an array instead of an object.
Using the first element of an array ("vevent") to identify its contents is not the best practice.

But anyway ... if this is the data source you are dealing with, this code should help you.

```
jq -r '..
       | arrays
       | select(.[0] == "vevent")[1]
       | [
           (.[] | select(.[0] == "dtstart") | .[3]),
           (.[] | select(.[0] == "dtend") | .[3]),
           (.[] | select(.[0] == "description") | .[3])
         ]
       | @csv
      '
```

Alternatively, the repeating code can be transferred into a function

```
jq -r 'def getField($name; $idx): .[] | select(.[0] == $name) | .[$idx];
       ..
       | arrays
       | select(.[0] == "vevent")[1]
       | [ getField("dtstart"; 3), getField("dtend"; 3), getField("description"; 3) ]
       | @csv
      '
```

**Output**

```json
"2015-02-18T10:58:12Z","2015-02-18T10:58:44Z","Phone call to +49xxxxxxxxxx lasted for 0 seconds."
"2015-01-09T17:23:16Z","2015-01-09T17:24:19Z","Phone call to +1xxxxxxxxxx lasted for 39 seconds."
```

---

You can also extract phone number and duration with the help of regular expressions in `jq`:

```
jq -r 'def getField($name; $idx): .[] | select(.[0] == $name) | .[$idx];
       ..
       | arrays
       | select(.[0] == "vevent")[1]
       | [
           getField("dtstart"; 3),
           getField("dtend"; 3),
           (getField("description"; 3) | match("call to ([^ ]*)") | .captures[0].string),
           (getField("description"; 3) | match("(\\d+) seconds")  | .captures[0].string)
         ]
       | @csv
      '
```

**Output**

```json
"2015-02-18T10:58:12Z","2015-02-18T10:58:44Z","+49xxxxxxxxxx","0"
"2015-01-09T17:23:16Z","2015-01-09T17:24:19Z","+1xxxxxxxxxx","39"
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe, I even follow the logic of this :D. And yes - that's jCal... awful....

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient solution, but quite understandable by first building an object out of key-value pairs and then filtering and transforming those.

`.[2][][1]` is a stream of events encoded as arrays.

Which means that:

```
.[2][][1]
  | map({key:.[0], value:.[3]})
  | from_entries
```

the above gives you a stream of objects; one object per event:

```json
{
  "dtstamp": "2015-04-05T16:42:10Z",
  "created": "2015-02-18T16:44:04Z",
  "uid": "9b23142b-8d86-3e17-2f44-2bed65b2e471",
  "last-modified": "2015-04-05T16:42:10Z",
  "description": "Phone call to +49xxxxxxxxxx lasted for 0 seconds.",
  "summary": "Outgoing: +49xxxxxxx",
  "dtstart": "2015-02-18T10:58:12Z",
  "dtend": "2015-02-18T10:58:44Z",
  "transp": "OPAQUE"
}
{
  "dtstamp": "2015-04-05T16:42:10Z",
  "created": "2015-01-09T19:12:05Z",
  "uid": "c337e092-a012-5f5a-497f-932fbc6159e5",
  "last-modified": "2015-04-05T16:42:10Z",
  "description": "Phone call to +1xxxxxxxxxx lasted for 39 seconds.",
  "summary": "Outgoing: +1xxxxxxxxxx",
  "dtstart": "2015-01-09T17:23:16Z",
  "dtend": "2015-01-09T17:24:19Z",
  "transp": "OPAQUE"
}
```

Now plug that into the final program: `select` the wanted objects, add CSV headers, build the rows and ultimately convert to CSV:

```
["start", "end", "description"],
(
  .[2][][1]
  | map({key:.[0], value:.[3]})
  | from_entries
  | select(.created | startswith("2015-01"))
  | [.dtstart, .dtend, .description]
)
| @csv
```

Raw output (`-r`):

```
"start","end","description"
"2015-01-09T17:23:16Z","2015-01-09T17:24:19Z","Phone call to +1xxxxxxxxxx lasted for 39 seconds."
```

If you need to further transform `.description`, you can use `split` or [`capture`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#capture(val),capture(regex;flags)). Or use a different property, such as `.summary`, in your CSV rows. Only a single line needs to be changed.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your answer! Unfortunately, I can only give one check mark...

Comment: @StefanGofferje no problem. Only you know which answer solves your problem best :)